# Migrate User Passwords from Liferay 4.4.2 to Liferay 6.0.6

Tags: liferay, database-migration, liferay-6

Have some users in Liferay 4.4.2 that are currently active, all having valid passwords.
Have the same users in Liferay 6.0.6, all of them added with a default password.

Can you suggest a way where I can migrate the passwords of users from Liferay 4.4.2 to Liferay 6.0.6?

Tried copying the passwords directy through DB in the users table (I know its not adviced, but I had to start somewhere).
Didn't work out.

The encryption algorithm used in both the versions is MD5. Is there a difference in the encoding digest?
There is no Digest Column in Liferay 4.4.2, but can see one in Liferay 6.0.6

How can I migrate the passwords?

Comment: Do you start a new instance rather than update the existing one? If you update, the update procedure should take care of this by itself. I don't know if there's a difference between the password hashing in these versions (but as you say so there probably is) - you might find the solution in the upgrade routines, but I can't tell you what version the upgrade would have appeared in. One thing: As you know it's not encouraged to change the database directly: You might just need to restart in order to get the changes picked up...

Comment: Yes. I did not use the same db. Used a new Instance. Tried restarting after the changes with no positive result. I've gone through the scripts, but could not find anything that'd change the password fields. Trying to isolate the Password hashing process of both Liferay versions and compare the results. Will post if I find anything. Thanks Olaf :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using Forgot Password functionality to intimate the users to change their passwords which I know is hectic. This is how I did it:

```java
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
Company company = themeDisplay.getCompany();
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest));
//Replace the variables with corresponding values
UserLocalServiceUtil.sendPassword(companyId, emailAddress, remoteAddr, remoteHost, userAgent, fromName, fromAddress, subject, body, serviceContext);
```

Any better solutions are welcome.